# Configure reporting in TFS 2010

Tags: team-foundation-server, ssrs

I am trying to configure TFS 2010 reporting and have come accross the following error:

> **Failed to add Domain\Development account to the TfsWarehouseDataReader role on the Tfs_Warehouse relational database**

I have set up reporting service on the machine and have used the NETWORK SERVICE as the service account and the database login and seems to be working OK.

In the Analysis Services and Reports tabs I have specified our domain admin for access to the datastore.

Looking at the database it created Domina\Development as a group (which I assume is correct as this is a group on the domain) but the TfsWarehouseDataReader is not ticked. I manually tick this and try finishing the configuration again and I get the same error.

Been looking all over google and can not find anything, can anyopne help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you grant the account "log on locally" permissions?

From the MSDN page on account requirements for the report reader: "You must specify a user account that has the Allow log on locally permission."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578625.aspx

Comment: When you say account do you mean the Domain\Development? As this is a group

Comment: No, the account is the report reader account. You need to give a domain account the log on locally permission. During tfs install you are prompted for this account. Not sure how its handled during "add reports" but you should make sure the account you used has the permissions it needs.

Comment: This is an old thread but I wanted to put in my current findings (We're running TFS 2010 here at work...  Still).  I'm receiving the same error as the OP except for a totally different service account that has nothing to do with TFS, and both it and all the service accounts already have the "Log on locally" permission by proxy of all domain users being part of the Users group on the server, and the Users group has "Log on locally" permission.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: You need to have your account that you're running the TFS Administration Console with added as a sysadmin to the database instance.  Also, it adds all users and groups in the [TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Service Accounts to the TFS_Warehouse database permissions for some strange reason.

This is a bit old, but I wanted to throw in my two cents here to give an update on what fixed this for me, and what I noticed:

We run TFS2010 here at work, and are working on moving our data center.  As part of that, I recently moved our reporting databases to a new server.

When I attempted to update the reporting information after the databases were moved, I got the message "Failed to add Domain\InterfaceSvc account to the TfsWarehouseDataReader role on the Tfs_Warehouse relational database"

Now, what strikes me as odd, is that the InterfaceSvc account has *nothing* to do with TFS administration, it is a service account used by a Windows Service on another server that makes calls to TFS every 5 minutes.  It's not part of any of the TFS administration settings, and there's no reason whatsoever for it to try to be added to this database.

First thing: Fix the error.  That was pretty simple, the DBA added my personal domain account to be a sysadmin of the database instance and the error went away and everything worked fine.

Second thing: That service account got added to the database.  As well as a few other accounts.  It took me some digging but it appears that any user and group in the [TEAM FOUNDATION]\Team Foundation Service Accounts security group gets added to the TFS_Warehouse database.  I have no idea why, but it appears to be consistent in both our Test and Production instances of TFS.